# Can't run gulp because of Error

Tags: gulp, frontend, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I just installed gulp in my project directory and it does not run because of this error. I have a secrets.json file in the directory, how can I make gulp work

```
Wuns-iMac:cayenna wunwun$ gulp
fs.js:641
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './.secrets.json'
        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
        at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:509:33)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wunwun/Documents/websites/cayenna/gulp/tasks/deploy.js:12:31)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at requireDir (/Users/wunwun/Documents/websites/cayenna/node_modules/require-dir/index.js:123:33)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/wunwun/Documents/websites/cayenna/gulpfile.js:5:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
        at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:198:16)
        at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:17:3)
        at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:190:9)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:164:9
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:110:14
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:38:12
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:49:7
```

Comment: Your error states that it is looking for .secrets.json file : note the dot before secrets.  It is looking for a file called .secrets.json   Remove that first dot.

Comment: @Mark thank you. I didn't think it would be so simple, as you said I removed the first dot contained in the deployment task which called for `./secrects.json`